# Penetrative property of radiation

Tags: radiation

On looking upon the process of penetration of radiation. I came upon this: "If the particle has enough energy, it can deposit its energy to break the molecular bonds displacing the electrons, hence it can penetrate the object. So, if the same thing is done in a large scale with higher concentration of radioactive particle hitting an object per unit area, would it be possible to break nearly every single molecular bonds, and resulting into the object breaking apart in dust?

Comment: One does this already with laser cutters